# Refer to arxiv version?

Tags: etiquette, arxiv, citations, mathematics

Am I breaking some kind of rule if I'm adding the arxiv link to the bibitem for an article that's published in a journal? I thought obviously not until I noticed that (link to arxiv) and (page number in journal) are quite mutually exclusive.

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/3050/why-are-some-sources-cited-twice-in-a-bibliography-once-with-doi-and-once-with

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No.**  I think giving the arxiv link is *fine*.  One alternative is to have two bibitem entries, one for the journal version and another for the arxiv version.  I find it valuable to include the journal reference, because that shows that the article has been refereed (so its claims gain legitimacy).  But I also see the value of including the arxiv version, particularly if the journal is hard to access.

Answer (score 6):

Many copy editors will remove arXiv links to published papers, but usually they'll put them back in if you insist.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, an arxiv version of a paper is different from a journal version. This can be a problem if you (for example) cite a particular theorem or lemma in a math paper that has a different number (or doesn't exist) in the arxiv version.

You didn't mention why you're adding the arxiv link. If you wish to add a link to a freely accessible document, then you could add a note in the text to that effect and cite the arxiv version in addition to the journal version. Otherwise, if you merely want a link to an online version, then you should be using the DOI link for the journal.

Comment: One adds the arxiv link to illustrate where the paper is freely available to everyone.